# Force Close on Button

Tags: android, button, android-activity, forceclose

Why is my app force closing when I hit the button to start the Activity of First

This is the startup Activity:

```
public class ForeverAlone extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button start;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ForeverAlone.this, First.class);
                ForeverAlone.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

    }
```

This is the Activity that is MEANT to come up after I hit the button:

```
public class First extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button firstNext;
    EditText firstFacebook, firstReallife;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);
        firstNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFirstNext);
        firstFacebook = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirst1);
        firstReallife = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirst2);
        firstNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        String firstFB = firstFacebook.getText().toString();
        String firstRL = firstReallife.getText().toString();
        DataHelper.insert(firstFB, firstRL);
    }



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            First.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
}
```

Any help at all will be appreciated!

[Edit]

Here's the LogCat:

```
01-08 19:19:55.656: D/dalvikvm(363): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 53% free 2553K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 76ms
01-08 19:19:57.966: D/AndroidRuntime(363): Shutting down VM
01-08 19:19:57.966: W/dalvikvm(363): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kenning.foreveralone/com.kenning.foreveralone.First}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:362)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:105)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.kenning.foreveralone.DataHelper.insert(DataHelper.java:9)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.kenning.foreveralone.First.onCreate(First.java:27)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-08 19:19:57.986: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 11 more
```

[Edit]

I've found the cause of the "force close" problem.

It's these lines of code:

```
String firstFB = firstFacebook.getText().toString();
String firstRL = firstReallife.getText().toString();
DataHelper.insert(firstFB, firstRL);
```

How do I stop the method from running into them and sort of skip them in a way?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse `01-08` (looks like the `toString()` of a `Date`) as an int in `DataHelper` at line 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the instance of the EditTexts

```
    firstFacebook = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirst1);
    firstReallife = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirst2);
```

then getting their values

```
    String firstFB = firstFacebook.getText().toString();
    String firstRL = firstReallife.getText().toString();
```

and using them here

```
    DataHelper.insert(firstFB, firstRL);
```

but the EditTexts are empty so you are essentially passing an empty string in, hence the

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
```

Comment: If I remove them, it screws up the rest of the application.  Can I get the method to ignore these lines?

Comment: add this if-statement before you insert in the db: `if(!firstFB.equals("") && !firstRL.equals(""))`.

Comment: The number is not equal to a certain value, it is defined by the user.

Comment: HAHAHAHA IT WORKED YES YES YES YES YES YES

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the logcat output, but my guess is that you have not listed `First` as an activity in your manifest. Either that, or something in `First.onCreate` is generating an exception.

Comment: @user1137178 The exception is happening inside DataHelper.insert. On line 9, it's trying to convert a String to an Integer and failing because the String is empty. As a guess, you can probably fix this by testing whether `firstFB.length() > 0` and/or `firstRL.length() > 0` (whichever makes sense for your app).

Answer (score 0):

You have a NumberFormatException. According to your logcat output you are inserting an empty string where an integer is expected in your Datahelper class:

```
at com.kenning.foreveralone.DataHelper.insert(DataHelper.java:9)
```